# Numbers: How to make a sum product of 2 columns numbers of which only those with checkboxes checked in a 3rd column respectively?

Tags: numbers

Say, sumproduct(A, B)=a1*b1 + a2*b2 + a3*b3, now I have many columns C, D,..., e.g. c1 checked, c2 unchecked, c3 checked; d1 unchecked, d2 checked, d3 checked;

Now I need a formulae which I want to put in a cell of each of column C, D... to compute a conditional sum product to get a1*b1 + a3*b3 and a2*b2 + a3*b3 respectively.

This can be used in my nutrition calculation table of daily intake.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have the same question, it looks odd because `TRUE * 2` gives 2 and `FALSE * 2` gives 0 (which is cool). But `SUMPRODUCT({FALSE; TRUE}; {2; 2})` doesn't seem to work. `{FALSE; TRUE}` gives `FALSE`. Maybe that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: I wonder why Numbers doesn't have a map function, that would solve so many problems like this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional column D, where D1 to D3 would contain:

```
IF(C1,1,0)
IF(C2,1,0)
IF(C3,1,0)
```

This would print a 1 if checked or a 0 if not checked, and you simply would need to add column D into your sumproduct:

```
a1*b1*c1 + a2*b2*c2 + a3*b3*c3
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I cannot accept this answer, I don't want introduce an auxiliary column. Actually, I have many columns C, D, E, F... all are with checkboxes..I need a conditional sum product formulae to compute and show the results for each column in a cell in the same column.